# AngularJS + Turbolinks: URL path gets popped

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, turbolinks

My application has an AngularJS function which calls `Turbolinks.visit(exampleUrl)`. Oftentimes, the execution of this AngularJS function results in the browser navigating to the desired page, but as soon as the new content finishes loading, the path in the address bar disappears (so the url is `https://www.example.com`).

My question is not what the cause could be (but if you know that, please share) but rather: do you have any ideas **how I can debug this behaviour?** Where should I put a debug point? (I've tried putting it in `Turbolinks.visit`, but that appears to execute entirely without producing the negative behaviour; indeed, when I run `Turbolinks.visit` from the Developer Tools console, it never produces the bug described above.)